# Mysql table relation for a user with multiple business

Tags: mysql, database-design

How to properly implement mysql table relation such that a user can create multiple business and each of those business can have multiple users. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  Create a table for the businesses, and another for the users.  I would then create a table that stores the key mapping which tells you which users are associated with each business and vice-versa.

CREATE TABLE Business
(BusinessID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
BusinessName VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (BusinessID));

CREATE TABLE Users
(UserID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Username VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (UserID));

CREATE TABLE BusinessUsers
(BusinessUserID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
UserID INT,
BusinessID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (BusinessUserID));

You can see it in action by inserting some data in those tables, and then running a simple INNER JOIN to see the results.

INSERT INTO Business (BusinessName) VALUES ('ACME Industries');

INSERT INTO Users (Username) VALUES ('JDOE');

INSERT INTO BusinessUsers (UserID, BusinessID)
SELECT B.BusinessID, U.UserID
FROM Business B
INNER JOIN Users U
WHERE U.Username = 'JDOE'
AND B.BusinessName = 'ACME Industries'

SELECT B.BusinessName, U.Username
FROM
Business B
INNER JOIN Users U
INNER JOIN BusinessUsers BU
ON B.BusinessID = BU.BusinessID
AND U.UserID = BU.UserID;

You should also have foreign keys between the ID columns on those tables, but you didn't mention which version of MySQL you're using.